# How to fill a cell based on the result of an If Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Let's say that I have three columns: `ID`, `Make`, and `Model`. I want to be able to have an if-Statement check the cells containing "Make" and "Model", and if they are a certain grouping, I want excel to be able to return the value that should go into "ID".

I hope this example demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish.

```
Id      Make            Model
34138   Honda           Accord
1946    Acura           MDX
368     Toyota          Camry
```

`A` column is "ID". `B` Column is "Make" `C` Column is "Model". Imagine ID is blank after Toyota Camry ID# 368 but Make and Model information is available in various combinations for hundreds of entries. I need the if Statement to check the B column and C Column and if "Honda" + "Accord" Lines up (there could be Honda Civic and the rest of the Honda fleet on this list) I want the ID to be put in automatically. If Honda and Accord, then ID = 34138

Comment: You may be better off with one or several lookup tables, and use one of the `LOOKUP` functions or `INDEX/MATCH` sequences. Otherwise your `IF` will become unwieldly, and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B100="Honda")*(C2:C100="Accord")*A2:A100)
```

or array formula -

```
{=INDEX(A2:A100,MATCH(1,(B2:B100="Honda")*(C2:C100="Accord"),0))}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Hi @basic. Excel is outputting the spill error/alert. Why do you think that is? Also, I was thinking the formula for this would be more based on like if B2...C2.... and then A outputs the ID number associated with those two conditions, Make and Model

Comment: Hey @basic I don't think I did the array correctly because nothing happened. The sumproduct output was 0. Now I wonder if the situation is an if then or an if else situation. I know what the ID is for a few entries. I want it to check row by row. Ideally, it should be like if B2=Honda and C2 =Accord A= (lets say) 123 else... leave that cell blank/output 0 in that cell.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I've attached a picture. Maybe it can help you. SUMPRODUCT can be used if ID is number and Make and Model are unique. INDEX will return the first match in either case.